# Win32 Mutex not waiting

Tags: winapi, ipc, mutex, fpc, waitforsingleobject

I am creating an application that implements inter process communication.
For this purpose I have set up a shared buffer, which seems to work fine.
Now, I need a way for the data generating application (written in c++) 
to tell the data receiving application (written in freepascal/lazarus) 
when it should read the data.

I was trying to use a mutex for this purpose. I do not have much experience with windows api programming.

So, my problem is, in the FreePascal code below, the mutex won't wait. I can call the TMutex.Wait() function, it doesn't return an error or anything, but it simply won't wait.

> constructor TMutex.Create(sName: AnsiString);
>   begin
>     sName  := 'Local\Mutex'+sName;
>     hMutex := CreateMutexA(
>           nil,               // default access
>           True,             // initially not owned
>           PChar(sName));     // named mutex
>     if hMutex = 0 then
>     begin
>       raise Exception.Create('mutex creation failed');
>     end;
>   end;
>   
>   destructor TMutex.Destroy;
>   begin
>     CloseHandle(hMutex);
>   end;
>   
>   procedure TMutex.Wait;
>   begin
>     if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) <> 0) then ShowMessage('debug: wait returned something');
>   end;
>   
>   procedure TMutex.Post;
>   begin
>     ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
>   end;

Comment: Named Pipes were invented for this purpose: IPC - via shared memory - with a handy ReadFile/WriteFile based API

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is at:

```
    True, // initially not owned
```

You have things backwards -- true means it initially IS owned, so waiting on it will return immediately.

Comment: tried both true and false, doesn't seem to make a difference. I had it origially false, changed it to true to see if that changed anything but didn't update the comment. Since it didn't change anything, I started to look elsewhere and forgot about that. Still, setting ti back to false doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

you don't show us the code that calls the Wait, method of TMutex. however, you have to know that a mutex is reentrant: if a thread owns a mutex, it will always be granted access to it, thus a wait will never block. this is built into the mutex to avoid deadlocks.

try acquiring the mutex from another thread, the wait should block.

Comment: Okay, now I got

uses sharedmem;


procedure TIPCThread.test ;
begin
  ShowMessage('blaat')
end;

procedure TIPCThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(@Test);
  BlaatSharedMem.Mutex.Wait;
  Synchronize(@Test);
end;


Still.... I got two ShowMessages with no wait between them. I did start a new thread here as you see, in which I do the waiting, but no difference, it doesn´t wait at all.